# How to find maximum of an inverse of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If there is a square $~n\times n~$ matrix $~H~$ where ALL the elements of $~H_{i,j}~$ are variables between two bounds, $~H_{i,j})_{min}~$ and $~H_{i,j})_{max}~$. Is there any relation to maximize $~H^{-1}~$ based on maximum or minimum (or other) value of $~H~$?

For example if we put the lower bounds of $~H_{i,j}~$ in $~H~$:
$$\pmatrix{H_{1,1})_{min}&H_{1,2})_{min}&\cr H_{2,1})_{min}&H_{2,2})_{min}}$$

which in that case norm of $~H~$ is minimum, can we say $~H^{-1}~$ is maximum. Is this sentence true? Is there any lemma or theorem?

I need to maximize $~H^{-1}~$ where the arrays of $~H~$ are variables, but I cannot find any rule in mathematics for this.

Example: Consider following matrix:$$H=\pmatrix{2a^2+5&-a\times cos(b)&\cr 4c^3&2b\sqrt{d}}$$ where $$2\le{a}\le{3}$$$$1\le{b}\le{4}$$$$1.5\le{c}\le{2}$$$$3\le{d}\le{4}$$How the variables $~a,b,c,d~$ should be selected to maximize $~H^{-1}~$? Is the answer minimum values of $~a,b,c,d~$? How do we deal with it generally when the matrix is $~n\times n~$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any other assumptions on $H$, such as $\det H$?

Comment: There is no constraint or assumption. Determinant is probably a key point in this problem, but I don't know how to connect it.

Comment: Define "norm of $H$".

Comment: @SaeedAref: Note that $H^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det H}H^*$

Comment: Dear Martin, I do not think the type of norm changes the main results. Lets define Frobenius norm for this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Dear Alfred, I was aware of that definition. Using that we should minimize determinant of $~H~$ and probably do something else. But I wonder if we could approach the solution by choosing a proper value for $~H~$. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$$\pmatrix{1+\epsilon&1\cr 1&1}^{-1}=\pmatrix{\frac1{\epsilon}&-\frac1{\epsilon}\cr-\frac1{\epsilon}&1+\frac1{\epsilon}}$$